# Ubuntu update asking for passphrase of secondary hard disk

Tags: mount, updates, hard-drive, encryption

I have an internal drive to store documents that is encrypted and not auto-mounted. I only mount the drive when I need to use it. The disk is mostly empty, it only has a few documents and VM on it right now.

In my latest update I was asked for its passphrase, I'm assuming the OS wanted to mount it: `Please enter passphrase for disk Samsung_SSD_850_EVO_500GB (diskfifi) on /mnt/diskfifi!`. I simply pressed <kbd>ENTER</kbd> without providing any kind of password and the update proceeded. At some point it asked me again for my password. I once again pressed enter and the update proceeded again.

After the update was complete, I called update/full-upgrade to check whether there were any pending updates, and everything appears to be fine. Why is Ubuntu asking me for the passphrase of the secondary hard disk?

An extract of the update follows. I've kept more than necessary for context and marked both lines with **.

```
Preparing to unpack .../ubuntu-core-launcher_2.26.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ubuntu-core-launcher (2.26.10) over (2.25) ...
Preparing to unpack .../snapd_2.26.10_amd64.deb ...
** Please enter passphrase for disk Samsung_SSD_850_EVO_500GB (diskfifi) on /mnt/diskfifi! 
Warning: Stopping snapd.service, but it can still be activated by:
  snapd.socket
Unpacking snapd (2.26.10) over (2.25) ...
Preparing to unpack .../logrotate_3.8.7-2ubuntu2.16.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking logrotate (3.8.7-2ubuntu2.16.04.2) over (3.8.7-2ubuntu2.16.04.1) ...

...

Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Setting up snapd (2.26.10) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.snapd.snap-confine.real ...
** Please enter passphrase for disk Samsung_SSD_850_EVO_500GB (diskfifi) on /mnt/diskfifi! 
Setting up ubuntu-core-launcher (2.26.10) ...
Setting up logrotate (3.8.7-2ubuntu2.16.04.2) ...

...

$ sudo apt update 
(...)
All packages are up to date.
$ sudo apt full-upgrade 
(...)
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```